# waypoint addClass and remove class of a "fixed" element works when going down but doesn't going up

Tags: javascript, parallax, jquery-waypoints

I'm working on a website with a parallax effect using Stellar:
*http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/*

I've got a "fixed" div with a class at the center of the page.
When I scroll down or up the class changes depending on the slide that is "active".

I'm using waypoint and everything works just fine when I'm scrolling down the page.
But when I scroll up, instead of changing the class, they are all put one after an other, the order is shifted and the class doesn't match the right slide.

Here is the HTML
(#square is the fixed div):

```
<body>

<ul class="navigation">
<li id="un"     data-slide="1">Slide 1</li>
<li id="deux"   data-slide="2">Slide 2</li>
<li id="trois"  data-slide="3">Slide 3</li>
<li id="quatre" data-slide="4">Slide 4</li>
<li id="cinq"   data-slide="5">Slide 5</li>
<li id="six"    data-slide="6">Slide 6</li>
<li id="sept"   data-slide="7">Slide 7</li>
<li id="huit"   data-slide="8">Slide 8</li>
<li id="neuf"   data-slide="9">Slide 9</li>
<li id="dix"    data-slide="10">Slide 10</li>
<li id="onze"   data-slide="11">Slide 11</li>
</ul>

<div id="square" class="trans1"></div>

<div class="slide" id="slide1" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
<a class="button" data-slide="2" title=""></a>

</div><!--End Slide 1-->

<div class="slide" id="slide2" data-slide="2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">

   <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="images/slide2/blur-ball.png" data-stellar-ratio="3" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-55"alt="">
      <img src="images/slide2/blur-ball-big.png" data-stellar-ratio="1" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-102"alt="">
   </div>

   <span class="slideno">Slide 2</span>
   <a class="button" data-slide="3" title=""></a>

</div><!--End Slide 2-->


<div class="slide" id="slide3" data-slide="3" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
   <div class="wrapper">
   <img src="images/slide3/freelance.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.4" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-102"alt="">
   <img src="images/slide3/psdtuts.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.5" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-53"alt="">
   <img src="images/slide3/rockable.png" data-stellar-ratio="2.7" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-200"alt="">
   <img src="images/slide3/themeforest.png" data-stellar-ratio="3" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-200"alt="">
   <img src="images/slide3/tutshub.png" data-stellar-ratio="1" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-200"alt="">
   <img src="images/slide3/psdtuts.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.5" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-200"alt="">
   </div>

   <span class="slideno">Slide 3</span>
   <a class="button" data-slide="4" title=""></a>

</div><!--End Slide 3-->

<div class="slide" id="slide4" data-slide="4" data-stellar-background-ratio="0">

   <span class="slideno">Slide 4</span>
   <span class="parallaxbg">Use the parallax effects on background images too!</span>

</div><!--End Slide 4-->
```

And here is the javascript

```
//1st SLIDE
    $('#square').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
        $('#square').toggleClass('trans1');
    }
    else {
        $('#square').toggleClass('trans1');
    }
    });

    // 2nd slide
    $('#slide2').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
        $('#square').toggleClass('trans2'), $('#square').removeClass('trans1');
    }
    else {
        $('#square').toggleClass('trans2'), $('#square').removeClass('trans1');
    }
    }, { offset: '50%' });

        $('#slide2').waypoint(function(direction) {
            if (direction === 'up') {
            $('#square').toggleClass('trans1'),$('#square').removeClass('trans2');
        }
        });

   //3rd slide
   $('#slide3').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
        $('#square').toggleClass('trans3'),$('#square').removeClass('trans2');
    }
    else {
        $('#square').toggleClass('trans3'),$('#square').removeClass('trans2');
    }}, { offset: '50%' });

        $('#slide3').waypoint(function(direction) {
                if (direction === 'up') {
            $('#square').toggleClass('trans2'),$('#square').removeClass('trans3');
            }
        });

    //4th slide
    $('#slide4').waypoint(function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
        $('#square').toggleClass('trans4'),$('#square').removeClass('trans3');
    }
    else {
        $('#square').toggleClass('trans4'),$('#square').removeClass('trans3');
    }}, { offset: '50%' });

        $('#slide4').waypoint(function(direction) {
                if (direction === 'up') {
            $('#square').toggleClass('trans3'),$('#square').removeClass('trans4');
            }
        });
```

Here's a link to the website : http://ambuscade.ca/DEV2/

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having created my portfolio site (http://anti-code.com) which does some crazy stuff along with parallax scrolling in all directions, the way you have your code structured could be done far more object oriented, and it would make things much less repetitive.

But besides all that.
The issue you are having is because you are not removing the classes. You are simply toggling the ones that are for each slide.

So for example, all instances where you have this:

```
   $('#square').toggleClass('trans2'),$('#square').removeClass('trans3');
```

Could be changed to something like this for it to work properly:

```
  $('#square').removeAttr('class').addClass('trans2');
```

If that makes sense. You aren't changing the class otherwise, you're just toggling ON the different trans# class name on the square element. If you just remove the class attribute first before toggling it, and then add the className which you want to turn on then it will work.